# Linked list/Strings/Pointers in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm a newbie and trying to learn C, but faced some problem in implementing strings and pointer in a linked list. I was required to build a preorder tree using a linked list and one problem came out.

BTW here are my codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct BinTreeNode {
    char *data ;
    struct BinTreeNode *left;
    struct BinTreeNode *right;
};

struct BinTreeNode *initBinTreeNode(char *data);

void visit(char *data);

void preorder(struct BinTreeNode *node);
void postorder(struct BinTreeNode *node);
void inorder(struct BinTreeNode *node);

int main(void)
{
    struct BinTreeNode *root, *parent1, *parent2;
  /* growing the tree */
    root = initBinTreeNode("5");
    root->left  = initBinTreeNode("Mee (F) & Keong (M)");
    root->right = initBinTreeNode("Saw (F)");
    parent1 = root->left;
    parent1->left  = initBinTreeNode("Min (F) & Heng (M)");
    parent1->right = initBinTreeNode("Ning (F)");
    parent2 = parent1->left;
    parent2->left  = initBinTreeNode("Rui (F)");
  /* traverse and print tree */
    printf("\nPreorder traversal:\t");  preorder(root);
    
    return(0);
}

void preorder(struct BinTreeNode *node)
{
    if (node){  /* if Node exists */
        visit(node->data);
        preorder(node->left);
        preorder(node->right);
    }
}

void visit(char *data)
{
    printf("%c -", *data);
}

struct BinTreeNode *initBinTreeNode(char *data)
{
    struct BinTreeNode *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct BinTreeNode));
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Memory allocation failed.");
        return NULL;
    }

    (*temp).data = data;
    (*temp).left = NULL;  
    (*temp).right = NULL;   
    return (temp);          
}
```

When I have {"5"},{"Mee (F) & Keong (M)"},{"Saw (F)"},{"Min (F) & Heng (M)"},{"Ning (F)"},{"Rui (F)"} in my list, it comes out only the first word is printed out like this:

```
Preorder traversal:     5 -M -M -R -N -S -
```

The preorder output that I want, should be:

```
Preorder traversal:     5 -Mee (F) & Keong (M) -Min (F) & Heng (M) -Rui (F) -Ning (F) -Saw (F) -
```

May I know, what I am missing? I would be really grateful for any help and advice!

[image: Illustration of Preorder tree]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you write code, it is wise to develop new functionality *in isolation* as much as possible, and get it to work perfectly, before introducing it into the whole. If you had tested `visit` when you first wrote it, you would have noticed the error, and known that the bug was in that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change line (%c - prints single character, in this case first character of data):

```
printf("%c -", *data);
```

To (%s - prints entire string):

```
printf("%s -", data);
```

Comment: !!!! Wow this really helped solving this problem that struggles me for hours! Thank you very much! Just another small request, can you explain a bit regarding the changes?

Comment: @youyiheng72 When this answer solves your problem, consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.